# GPS Module don't provide full data

Tags: serial, gps, esp32

I connected my gps module (NEO-6M) with esp32doit-devkit-v1 board. The module provided data but many data are missing.

#### My pin configuration:

GPS ------- ESP32 
VCC ------- 3v3 
GND ------- GND 
TX -------- RX2 (pin 16) 
RX -------- TX2 (pin 17)

#### Baud Rate: 9600

My code:

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <TinyGPS++.h>

#define TXD2 17
#define RXD2 16

TinyGPSPlus gps;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial2.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, RXD2, TXD2);
  Serial.println("Started......");
}

void loop()
{
  while (Serial2.available())
  {
    Serial.write(Serial2.read());
    // gps.encode(Serial2.read());
    // if (gps.location.isValid())
    // {
    //   Serial.print("Latitude= ");
    //   Serial.print(gps.location.lat(), 6);
    //   Serial.print(" Longitude= ");
    //   Serial.println(gps.location.lng(), 6);
    // }
  }
}
```

#### OUTPUT

[image: my output]

Comment: The output looks perfectly fine. You just don't have a GPS signal.

Comment: @Majenko is right put your GPS outside (in open sky) then you will the latitude and longitude with other parameters as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPS seems to be working and informing you that you have no signal.  Usually happens inside buildings, when far from a window or when antenna isnt properly connected.

Testing out of doors is many times not possible, so try placing your antenna next to a window with a partial view of the sky.  Wait for a couple of minutes until you get a fix on 4 or 5 satellites.

Comment: have also found this happens when the power to the module is lower than needed, for example 5v being shared with other modules such as a 1602 display